# Vectorized nested indexing

Tags: c, performance, indexing, lapack, blas

I have a for-loop to do indexing:

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    a[i] = b[c[i]]
}
```

`c` are the indices of interest and are `int *`, while `b` and `a` are `float *` and the manipulated values.

But, this takes a long time (and it can't take that long). I'd like to have some vectorizing version, most likely found in BLAS/LAPLACK/etc.

I'm looking for `nested_indexing(float * output_vector, float * input_vector, int * input_indices)`.

I've tried looking through the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009465), but have not found anything.

Comment: What you need is a gather instruction - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193434/avx2-gather-instructions-load-address-calculation . Not sure if there are supporting libs

Comment: Have you looked at `?lapmt` and `?laswp` from LAPACK?  They do something similar (if you don't mind the fact that the matrix is permuted in-place, not copied.)

Answer (score 1):

`vDSP_vgathr` does exactly this. It takes in two `float *`'s and one `int *`. It does the equivalent of `for (i=0; i<N; i++) a[i] = b[c[i]]`.

The wording they used was

> Uses elements of vector B as indices to copy selected elements of vector A to sequential locations in vector C

It could be sequential indexing too, perhaps. I've noticed that the hardest part about finding these obscure functions is finding the right words to use in your searches.