# Memory access error with _mm512_i64gather_pd()

Tags: c++, avx512, knights-landing

I am trying to use a very simple example of the AVX-512 gather instructions:

```
double __attribute__((aligned(64))) array3[17] = {1.0,  2.0,  3.0,  4.0,  5.0,  6.0,  7.0,  8.0,
                     9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0,
                    17.0};
int __attribute__((aligned(64))) i_index_ar[16] = {1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
__m512i i_index = _mm512_load_epi64(i_index_ar);
__m512d a7AVX = _mm512_i64gather_pd(i_index, &array3[0], 1);
```

Unfortunetly, my last call to `_mm512_i64gather_pd` results in an memory access error (memory dumped).

Error message in German: `Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)`

I am using Intel Xeon Phi (KNL) 7210.

edit: The error here was, that I was using 32 bit integers with 64bit load instructions and **scale** in `_mm512_i64gather_pd` has to be 8 or `sizeof(double)`.

Comment: If your indices are really that simple, you should just us an unaligned SIMD load, not a gather.  Using `i32gather` would be much better than using 64-bit indices, saving memory bandwidth.  `VPGATHERQPD` and `VPGATHERDPD` have the same performance on KNL, so there's no downside to using 32-bit indices with the corresponding gather instruction.  A smaller cache footprint is definitely better.

Comment: thank you, but I simplyfied the example to understand this instruction. I will consider the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to set `scale` to `sizeof(double)`, not 1.

Change:

```
__m512d a7AVX = _mm512_i64gather_pd(i_index, &array3[0], 1);
```

to:

```
__m512d a7AVX = _mm512_i64gather_pd(i_index, &array3[0], sizeof(double));
```

See also: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16193434/253056) and its answers for a fuller explanation of Intel SIMD gathered loads and their usage.

—

Another problem: your indices need to be 64 bit ints, so change:

```
int __attribute__((aligned(64))) i_index_ar[16] = {1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8, 9, ...
```

to:

```
int64_t __attribute__((aligned(64))) i_index_ar[16] = {1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8, 9, ...
```

Comment: @boraas: or better, use [`_mm512_i32gather_pd` (`vgatherdpd`)](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VGATHERDPS:VGATHERDPD.html): dword indices, if your index data is 32-bit.  Otherwise you could load it with [`vpmovzxdq`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PMOVZX.html) or `vpmovsxdq` (zero or sign-extend to 64-bit) to get a 64-bit index vector.